# Is it possible to map automatic EF EntitySets to OData Model Builder?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, odata

I'm just started to integrate OData in my API project with EF installed.
Now the tutorials show that you have to map each model to an entity set like this:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.EntitySet<Artist>("Artist");
builder.EntitySet<Event>("Event");
builder.EntitySet<Genre>("Genre");
builder.EntitySet<Location>("Location");
builder.EntitySet<NewsItem>("NewsItem");
builder.EntitySet<Page>("Page");
builder.EntitySet<Performance>("Performance");
builder.EntitySet<Sponsor>("Sponsor");
```

Is there a way to do this automatic to all models?
So there is a new model or one gets deleted, we don't have to update this code.

Something like:

```
builder.EntitySets(MyDbContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Current OData Web API implementation cannot fill you needs and there is a new .Net library available that can full fill your needs currently named Domain Framework. You can take a look and try with it on Github https://github.com/OData/DomainFramework. The tutorial is at https://github.com/OData/DomainFramework/wiki/Northwind-Sample---Part-1. Please be noted that this library is still an alpha version, but also it means that we are open to all kinds of feedback.